# Enable click-and-drag scrolling in Windows 8 / Metro?

Tags: mouse, windows-8, modern-ui

In Windows 8 (Metro interface) I find myself trying to click and drag the background to scroll again and again, which does not work (I'm using a mouse, not touch). Also, scrolling with the scroll wheel, the bottom scrollbar, or the cursor keys is not nearly as smooth as I've seen in videos, or on tablets.

Is there any way to enable smooth kinetic scrolling with the mouse? So that I can click and drag lists or multi-screen displays around?

I remember seeing this in a video. I'm not sure if there was some third-party tool involved or not.

Comment: I haven't found an option to do so. It reacts to mouse wheel only. (I use Windows 8 on a regular laptop.) Sometimes, however, I think I saw a kinetic motion if the scroll area is large and I turn the wheel fast.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding the question, but for me the scroll wheel scrolls left to right very smoothly. I assumed you are wanting this to work on the start screen. Is it possible your scroll wheel settings are at issue? I will say when I first started using Win8, I found myself trying to click and drag quite often...

Answer (score 2):

There is an [Autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) solution to this. It can emulate scrolling in a way similar to what you describe. I have made a script which emulates dynamic scrolling with mouse movement.
Here is github link with thorough description and how-to:
https://github.com/Mikhail22/drag-scroll--autohotkey

I've been using it for 2 years, it's stable and well tested. I must say it is very comfortable, definitely way better than the wheel. I just can't live without it now. Some apps may scroll worse than others though. For example in Notepad++ it lags a bit, OTOH Firefox with enabled smooth scrolling feels perfect.

Note that it binds scroll mode to the right mouse button - it is best option I could find so far. Follow the link for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried click and drag in IE10 in Windows 8 release preview and was able to execute click and drag. Maybe I misunderstood your question? I posted a screenshot of my click and drag with a mouse. I don't remember trying the click and drag in the developer preview. Which Windows 8 are you using? Release Candidate? Developer?

[image]

Comment: You clicked with the middle mouse button and then entered the scrolling mode of IE? I meant something different: In the 'Metro' interface, *press* the left mouse button on the background, don't release it yet, and move it to the left. I'd expect the screen to scroll to the left (revealing new content on the right), exactly like it would have if I had touched and swiped the screen.

Comment: Ohhhhh right. I understand. That would be a very cool feature. I'm going to research that.