# Scroll with mouse like smartphone

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, mouse, smartphone

I there a way to make your mouse scroll as if I were on a smartphone?

Something like the device toolbar using Chrome *development mode* but for every single program... Or at least some of them.

An external application is ok, I'm using Windows 10.

I already know about `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Simulator\15.0\Microsoft.Windows.Simulator.exe`, but:

- There isn't such a folder under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared`
- If I'm not wrong I cannot use it in fullscreen mode, while I would like something for an "every day purpose", not for app testing

Thank you for any answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://superuser.com/q/464395/456981

Comment: see my answer in the linked question https://superuser.com/a/1350723/456981

Comment: @MikhailV it works but there's a bug... What's the minimum value for "k" under settings? If I try to edit it (it's tooo fast) it doesn't work anymore

Comment: Anyway, if you want to answer the question I'll accept it

Comment: ok, you can post issues on github for questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no native feature yet that supports the drag scrolling. But there are 3d party solutions, google for "drag scroll".
I have made an Autohotkey app to support drag scrolling with the right mouse button.
https://github.com/Mikhail22/drag-scroll--autohotkey