# Emulate touchscreen/pan hand scrolling with a HID mouse

Tags: windows-10, drivers, mouse, scrolling

The Synaptics driver for my X220 used to have 3 different middle mouse button modes:

1. TrackPoint is always mouse, MMB is MMB
2. Pressing MMB turns TrackPoint into a scroll wheel
3. TrackPoint is always mouse, MMB is pan-hand grab (like scrolling with a touch screen)

Is there some way to replicate mode 3 on Windows with a regular 3 button HID mouse? I have a keyboard that technically has a TrackPoint but it only looks like a normal HID mouse to Windows. The keyboard's firmware allows it to replicate mode 1 or 2.

If there is no straight forward way to do this in Windows natively, is there any software or custom user mode drivers that could replicate mode 3?

Edit: From what I recall, pressing the MMB with mode 3 in a CAD program would still emulate a 3 button mouse as you would expect, but *doesn't* trigger the weird joystick like scrolling in browsers and such.

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/1544118/456981

Comment: @mikhail-v all of the answers there are mode 2 scrolling not mode 3. they emulate scrolling with the wheel not the trackpoint-pan-hand style scrolling.

Comment: Depends on what pan-hand exactly is, if it's just sensitivity, the AHK solution can be adjusted. Anyway, on Windows desktop there is no such scrolling as on Android. There is only wheel up/down events , and the scrollbar that you can hold and drag. At least for classic Windows applications.